# JavaScript Required Validation on Input not working

Tags: javascript

I have 2 simple JS function  one checks values of 2 input fields and triggers the other function Here is the code

```
function ValidateForm()
    {
    var name = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
     var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
     if(name.value= '' || email.value='')
     {
     alert('fields Empty');
     }
     else
     {
     UpdateRecord();
     }

    }


    function UpdateRecord()
    {
    var Qact = getQueryVariable('ACT');
        if(Qact==2){

            var picture= document.getElementById('myPic').src;
            activity.setUpdates(name,email,picture);
            }
            else
            {
            activity.CheckEmail(name,email);
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<button onClick="ValidateForm();" data-role="button" >Register</button>
```

if I call `UpdateRecord()` on button click it works fine but when i use `ValidateForm()` nothing works. The firefox debugger don't even go to the `ValidateForm()` Function

Comment: you are asigning value , not matching `valuename.value= ''` use`==`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment reiterating my answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(name.value= '' || email.value='')
```

should be

```
if(name === '' || email === '')
```

Comment: thanks it worked but now its calling UpdateRecord() even when input fields are empty . . .

Comment: See my update. You were trying to reference `element.value.value`

Comment: It didn't worked for me , but this did if(name.value == null || email.value == null) but you pointed out the basic mistake thanks :-)

Comment: No, `name.value` would be null because you were doing `document.getElementById('foo').value` <-- notice the .value. Then you were looking at the .value again. So of course `name.value.value` would be undefined, or falsy null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to compare values:

```
if(name.value == '' || email.value == '')
{
    alert('fields Empty');
}
else
{
    UpdateRecord();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(name.value== '' || email.value=='')
{
    alert('fields Empty');
}
else
{
    UpdateRecord();
}
```